# How to ensure you clicked on an ellipse object from a list?

Tags: c#, list, ellipse

I have a list with ellipse objects with the parameters (Point Begin, Point End, Color c). Now I want to ensure when I click somewhere if I did hit an ellipse.

I also do this with rectangles which already works and looks something like this:

```
 case 3: // Rectanglefill
        return p.X >= Begin.X && p.X <= End.X && p.Y >= Begin.Y && p.Y <= End.Y;
```

In this method I only want to return the bool True if I have a hit and False if the mouse click didn't hit something.

Now for the ellipse I already have this:

```
case 4: // Ellipsfill
/*  int radiusx = Math.Abs(End.X - Begin.X) / 2;
    int radiusy = Math.Abs(End.Y - Begin.Y) / 2;
    int midpointx = (Begin.X + End.X) / 2;
    int midpointy = (Begin.Y + End.Y) / 2;

return ((Math.Pow((p.X -midpointx) / radiusx, 2) + Math.Pow((p.Y - midpointy) / radiusy, 2)) > 1);
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Is it on purpose you have commented some of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation is Ok, you just have to put `<1` (or `<=1` if you want to include the points on the ellipse) instead of `>1`

```
case 4: // Ellipsfill
    double radiusx = Math.Abs((double)End.X - (double)Begin.X) / 2.0;
    double radiusy = Math.Abs((double)End.Y - (double)Begin.Y) / 2.0;
    double midpointx = ((double)Begin.X + (double)End.X) / 2.0;
    double midpointy = ((double)Begin.Y + (double)End.Y) / 2.0;

return ((Math.Pow((p.X -midpointx) / radiusx, 2) + Math.Pow((p.Y - midpointy) / radiusy, 2)) < 1.0);
```

Comment: You were using integers instead of float or double and therefore you were getting the integer division. Try the code now when everything is converted to doubles. Try the edited code.